# Where can you see all processes created in process builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I'm able to see the processes which I have created. There is another user in my sandbox not able to see processes which I have created. How can a user see all the processes created through process builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Using Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000035wMDAAY) documentation:

> To create, edit, or view
>   processes:
>   • “Manage Force.com
>   Flow”
>   AND
>   “View All Data”